# Emacs bulk indent for Python while `cua-mode` is enabled

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, cua-mode

I'd like to know how to indent multiple lines while Python is my major mode. The link below answers my question for the most part:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585091/emacs-bulk-indent-for-python

However, is there a way to accomplish this while you have the following line in your `.emacs` file?

`(cua-mode t)`

When I attempt `C-c >` while `cue-mode` is enabled, nothing happens.

Comment: `C-h k C-c >` when `cua-mode` is not enabled, to find out what the command is. Then bind that command to some other key (globally or only in `cua-mode`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  The documentation for `cua-mode` (which can be accessed with C-h f cua-mode) says you have three options:

- press the prefix key twice very quickly (within 0.2 seconds),
- press the prefix key and the following key within 0.2 seconds, or
- use the SHIFT key with the prefix key, i.e. C-S-x or C-S-c.

Alternatively, as others have said, just make your own binding for the `python-indent-shift-left` and `python-indent-shift-right` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Binding it in `use-package` worked for me:

```
(use-package python
  :mode ("\\.py\\'" . python-mode)
  :bind (:map  python-mode-map
         ("C->" . python-indent-shift-right)
         ("C-<" . python-indent-shift-left))

;; more config...

)
```

The three options described by @stevoooo did not work when I had a region selected.
And I personally do not find practical to type in the 0.2 second range.